# Handle i18n in next@13.4.13 but with pages architecture

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13, i18next

Working in quite insane env, next is on `@13.4.13` but using `pages` architecture and i need to integrate `i18n`. Any ideas what is the best approach to execute it